# Correct simplification of an expression with Big O notation

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I have an expression roughly like
$$
x = \frac{y}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{y^2 - \frac{2 (y + \sqrt{y})}{\lambda^2}}}{2}
$$
where $\lambda$ is a small constant in $(0, 1]$ and $y$ is a very large variable compare to $\lambda$.
Can I get a conclusion like $$
x\ge y - O(\sqrt{y})?
$$

I wasn't sure about how to expand $\sqrt{y^2 - \frac{2 (y + \sqrt{y})}{\lambda^2}}$...

---

Edit, change $\ge$ to $=$, i.e., $x= y - O(\sqrt{y})$?

Comment: Hint: assuming $y>0$ (so $\sqrt{y}$ isn't imaginary), write$$\sqrt{y^2-\frac{2(y+\sqrt{y})}{\lambda^2}}=y\sqrt{1-\frac{2(1+1/\sqrt{y})}{\lambda^2y}}\in y\left(1-\frac{y^{-3/2}}{\lambda^2}+o(y^{-3/2})\right)\subseteq y-O(y^{-1/2}).$$

Comment: Using inequality sign $\geqslant$ with big-$O$ needs explicit definition.